# C# Using function from another file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Ok, so, I have functions.cs file where i stored following function

```
        public static void Global_Reset()
        {
            Form1 blok = new Form1();

            blok.userControl1.Visible = false;
            blok.userControl2.Visible = false;
            blok.userControl3.Visible = false;

            if (Properties.Settings.Default.client == 1)
            {
                blok.userControl1.Visible = true;
                MessageBox.Show("First");
            }
            else if (Properties.Settings.Default.client == 2)
            {
                blok.userControl2.Visible = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Second");
            }
            else if (Properties.Settings.Default.client == 3)
            {
                blok.userControl2.Visible = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Third");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
        }
```

When I call `fun.Global_Reset()` in Form1 or in any user control that is used in Form1, visibility never changes but I got messages (First, Second, Third). Is there any way to solve this?

I tried to use this directly in Form1 and it used to work, but when I call it from userControl that was used in Form1 it's not working again.

Comment: Make `Form1 blok` a parameter of the method (eg. `public static void Global_Reset(Form1 blok)`), and then pass a reference to the actual form when calling the method - otherwise you're just creating a _new_ instance of your form.

Comment: You're controlling the visibility of this *new* form, not the one you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

This is the form you're modifying:

```
Form1 blok = new Form1();
```

It only exists during the scope of that method (function), and it is never shown to the user.  It's *not* the form instance you're seeing on the screen.

As an analogy... Imagine the form you're seeing is a car.  What you're doing is getting another car that looks just like it and putting something in the trunk of that car, then noticing that what you put in the trunk of the second car can't be found in the trunk of the first car.

Instead of creating a new form instance, pass the existing instance to this method:

```
public static void Global_Reset(Form1 blok)
{
    // don't create an instance here, just use the blok that was passed
}
```

Then pass that instance from your form, for example:

```
fun.Global_Reset(this);
```

Comment: That's okay now for first load of Form1, but how do i use fun.Global_Reset(); in user controls that are in Form1? What's going in brackets?

Comment: @xShuki: You'd still need to include a reference to that form instance.  Do the user controls have [a reference to the form instance that contains them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform)?  In that case it might be something like: `fun.Global_Reset((Form1)this.ParentForm);`

Comment: I have no idea how is that working, but I copied it and that's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!